# Making a PHP/MySQL Timestamp look more attractive

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, date-formatting

So basically, I'm currently selecting a Timestamp from my MySQL database. In the database, the timestamp looks like so:

`2010-06-30 12:36:08`

Obviously for a webapp, that's not very attractive for users to view. So, using some CodeIgniter functions, I made it look a bit nicer.

```
<h4 class="timestamp">
    <?php // Quickly calculate the timespan
    $post_date = mysql_to_unix($row->date);
    $now = time();
    echo timespan($post_date, $now);?> ago
</h4>
```

If you don't do CodeIgniter, everything's standard PHP except for `echo timespan()`. CodeIgniter just echoes it as an 'English' timespan. So, an example output would be:

`2 Months, 4 Weeks, 5 Hours, 20 Minutes ago`

That's all well and good, but, I want to make it seem nicer still... there are too many commas and its all a tad too long (I know, I'm picky...). What I'd **like** is:

1. If the timespan is less than a day old, the output should be `7 hours, 33 minutes ago`
2. If the timespan is less than a week old, the output should be `4 days ago`
3. If the timespan is less than a month old, the output should be `2 weeks, 6 days ago`
4. If the timespan is over a month old, the output should be `4 months ago`
5. In the eventual case of the timespan being over a year old, the output should be `Over a year ago`

As you can see, I'm currently using a CodeIgniter function to simplify this - but if there's any native PHP function that can do what I want it to, that'll be awesome.

Thanks for your help!

Jack

Comment: Not that i know of. Just make yourself a custom utility function for that (Helper or somethingin CI)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is best done on the client side in the presentation layer. Here is a JS solution:**

[Timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to support automatically updating fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago").

Timeago will turn all abbr elements with a `class` of timeago and an ISO 8601 timestamp in the `title`:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

into something like this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="July 17, 2008">about a year ago</abbr>
```

**To convert the date into the ISO 8601 format you can do something like this:**

```
<?= date("c", $post_date) ?>
```

**Examples:**

> You opened this page less than a
>   minute ago. (This will update every
>   minute. Wait for it.)
>
> This page was last modified 11 days
>   ago.
>
> Ryan was born 31 years ago.

Comment: Thats supergreat, allows for caching.

Comment: That's interesting, but it's not a PHP solution. Also the way it's worded, it's unclear what `date("c", $post_date)` has to do with anything (I even thought you were saying that was outputting what's below).

Comment: @Artefacto: it's because you didn't read the Timeago page. It works elements with a `class` of `timeago` and an ISO 8601 timestamp in the `title`. the `date()` PHP function call above yields an ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @Artefacto: I hope you see the need for the ISO 8601 format now. I think StackOverflow uses something similar: `<span title="2010-07-02 21:31:32Z" class="relativetime">52 mins ago</span>`

Comment: @Bak Yes, it's better now. +1

Comment: @Bak SO definitely does it server-side.

Comment: @Art: Yeah the SO is server-side since it doesn't change until we refresh the page. Seems their `title` field is just for the popup. I watched Joel's presentation about SO on Google TechTalk, seems they use jQuery, they should use Timeago xD

Comment: Cheers Bakkai, it might not be PHP-based but it's definitely the most efficient solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ts = new DateTime();
$ts->setTimestamp($my_timestamp);
$cur = new DateTime();
$difference = $cur->diff($ts);
if ($difference->format("%a") == 0)
    $out = $difference->format("%h hours %i minutes");
elseif ($difference->format("%a") < 7)
    $out = $difference->format("%a days");
elseif ($difference->format("%m") == 0) {
    $days = $difference->format("%a");
    $out = sprintf("%d weeks %d days", floor($days / 7),
        $days % 7);
}
elseif ($difference->format("%y") == 0)
    $out = $difference->format("%m months");
else
    $out = "over a year";
```

You'll have to make a few adjustments if you don't want stuff like "1 days".

Comment: Thanks, Artefacto for the PHP-based solution. Did you just write this off the top of your head, or had you seen this before? It's pretty clever.

Comment: @Jack I wrote it especially for the occasion :)