# Unix timestamp to seconds, minutes, hours

Tags: php, mysql

I need to somehow take a unix timestamp and output it like below

Can this be done with MySQL? Or php

```
Mike                             7s ago
Jim                              44s ago
John                             59s ago
Amanda                           1m ago
Ryan                             1m ago
Sarah                            1m ago
Tom                              2m ago
Pamela                           2m ago
Ruben                            3m ago
Pamela                           5h ago
```

As you can guess i only wanna print the minute, not minutes and seconds(1m 3s ago)

What should I look into?

Answer (score 15):

Yes it can be done. [See related post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/245108?StartDate=2010-07-01&EndDate=2010-07-16)

```
$before // this is a UNIX timestamp from some time in the past, maybe loaded from mysql
$now = time()

$diff = $now - $before;
if( 1 > $diff ){
   exit('Target Event Already Passed (or is passing this very instant)');
} else {
   $w = $diff / 86400 / 7;
   $d = $diff / 86400 % 7;
   $h = $diff / 3600 % 24;
   $m = $diff / 60 % 60; 
   $s = $diff % 60;

   return "{$w} weeks, {$d} days, {$h} hours, {$m} minutes and {$s} secs away!"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

PHP 5.3 and newer have [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects that you can construct with data coming back from a database.  These `DateTime` objects have a [`diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method to get the difference between two dates as a [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, which you can then [`format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Edit: corrected `sub` to `diff`.

Edit 2:
Two catches with doing it this way:

1. `DateTime`'s constructor doesn't appear to take a UNIX timestamp... unless prefixed with an @, like this: `$startDate = new DateTime('@' . $timestamp);`
2. You won't know what the largest unit is without manually checking them.  To get an individual field, you still need to use format, but with just a single code... Something like `$years = $dateDiff->format('y');`

Comment: +1 if you're new to PHP date handling, use `DateTime` from the start. It's way better than timestamps.

Comment: I made a mistake and used sub instead of diff.  I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sECONDS_TO_DHMS($seconds)
{

    $days = floor($seconds/86400);
    $hrs = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $mins = intval(($seconds / 60) % 60); 
    $sec = intval($seconds % 60);

    if($days>0){
        //echo $days;exit;
        $hrs = str_pad($hrs,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $hours = $hrs-($days*24);
        $return_days = $days." Days ";
        $hrs = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }else{
        $return_days="";
        $hrs = str_pad($hrs,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    $mins = str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $sec = str_pad($sec,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

    return $return_days.$hrs.":".$mins.":".$sec;
}

echo sECONDS_TO_DHMS(2); // Output 00:00:02
echo sECONDS_TO_DHMS(96000); // Output 1 Days 02:40:00
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

as well as [time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and some others that are linked in those docs

This can also be done in Mysql with [date and time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions

Answer (score 0):

You can try my `Timeago` suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169194/making-a-php-mysql-timestamp-look-more-attractive/3169219#3169219).

It can give outputs like this:

> You opened this page **less than a
>   minute ago**. (This will update every
>   minute. Wait for it.)
>
> This page was last modified **11 days
>   ago**.
>
> Ryan was born **31 years ago**.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a mysql server at hand, but a combination of the following commands should get you something like what you want.

[DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

AND

[DATEFORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)